# Postprocess JSON output or alter SQL Query for a Flask API?

Tags: python, sql, json, flask, api-design

I have a Flask API that queries a SQL database. GET requests return a JSON output. Since I'm primarily a python developer, I am more comfortable looping through the JSON when sorting or filtering arguments are passed to the API. But I fear that this will lead to poor performance if the JSON output is too large.

Is there a significant performance degradation in postprocessing a JSON output compared to SQL queries with ORDER BY or WHERE clauses? Is there a standard/recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively I would say querying/filtering data from a database will be more efficient then requesting everything back, loading it in memory and doing your filtering there.

To answer this question with any accuracy you'll have to write a realistic use case and implement it using JSON in memory filtering and database querying. Then run the two implementations and using [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to see which is fastest.

For the test to be realistic it should also be run in your hosting environment against your hosted database and not on your machine to take in network lag/machine performance.

If you're uncomfortable with writing complex SQL statements, I'd suggest using something [SQLAlchemy ORM](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/) which presents an object oriented interface to your database, but that's really another conversation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen the syntax of SQLAlchemy ORM that you have mentioned often when researching flask APIs. I do feel that this is better but I have a very large database with many tables and columns. Writing them all out in the SQLAlchemy ORM seems like a pain. Is there an automated way of doing this from say a .dbml or .sql file?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to generate the python codes from an sql file, but you can do the reverse. The same guy who made SQLAlchemy has a database migration tool called Alembic. It's basically python code to describe changes to databases. You can also use ORM code from this to generate your tables. It's a handy tool when you have to handle production/staging/dev environments with different states of database versions. My data objects are only defined in one place, which is versioned and I have a means of moving the database back and forth between versions.

Comment: Just another comment, I've never added SQLAlchemy to a large project that already had many of tables but I've used it on several projects now, and never felt it was particularly a burden to write the ORM class code/alembic migrations. Also alembic has an autogenerate feature that looks at how your models have changed and takes a best guess at the migration to match it. You still have to test and adjust it sometimes but removes all the manual SQL writing. Some people treat ORM libraries like the devil, but I've found it fine in several projects now.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I do realize that SQLAlchemy ORM is the ideal solution, but I've found that it has a significant learning curve compared to Flask API that just calls SQL queries or SQL stored procedures directly.